# Show the next argument list item in the buffer after deleting the current item from the argument list

Tags: vim

## Context

The idea is to remove "processed" files from the args list as I finish with them. Say I've loaded a bunch of files into Vim's argument list. I'm going through them one at a time. Sometimes, I want to remove a file from the argument list, because I'm done with it, and then I want to move to the next file in the list. That's what the three step dance does. By the end of doing this dance for a while, the argument list contains only the files that I still need to process. In this situation, processing means reading a file deeply for understanding.

## What have I tried?

My current approach is to delete the current item from the argument list, then go to the next, then return to the previous.

```
:argdel %
:next
:prev
```

## What would I like?

What I would like is a single command to delete the current item from the argument list and replace the buffer contents with the new current item.

Comment: What, exactly is the point of that dance?

Comment: Thank you. You might want to add this to the question itself.

Comment: Can you not just do `:next` followed by `:argdelete #`? Or as a command `:command MoveOn next|argdelete #`

Comment: @PeterRincker Thx for that approach where `#` is the alternate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the commands:

```
:%argd|n|N<CR>
```

which is really one command and not substantially longer than your first one.

You can create a custom command:

```
:command! MyCommand %argdelete | next | Next
```

Comment: Chaining works with `:argd%|next|prev` or `:argd%|n|N` . When I used `%argd|next|prev` or `%argd|n|N`, I received an error saying, "E163: There is only one file to edit."